# Bootstrap Carousel slide not working and format too

Tags: html, css, carousel

I followed the professor's instructions correctly, however this is the result. Someone can help me please?
[My example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X01Nb.png)

This is how the professor has done:
[Professor's carousel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwsAZ.png)

```
<div class="container"><!--Start row contents-->
    <div class="row row-content">
        <div class="col">
            <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-indicators">
                  <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
                  <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
                  <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                  <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img src="img/uthappizza.png" class="d-block img-fluid" alt="uthappizza">
                  </div>
                  <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="img/buffet.png" class="d-block img-fluid" alt="buffet">
                  </div>
                  <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="img/alberto.png" class="d-block img-fluid" alt="alberto">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="prev">
                  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                </button>
                <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="next">
                  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                </button>
              </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly. We can't "debug" screenshots, and [a mere "can someone help me" is not considered an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1427878)

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and it's working. I guess you mean why in your professor's version you can see some pictures on the carousel, but not in your version. You can easily do that by adding captions to your slides with the `.carousel-caption` element within any `.carousel-item`. You can read more about it on the following page:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/carousel/

```html
<div class="container">
        <!--Start row contents-->
        <div class="row row-content">
            <div class="col">
                <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
                    <div class="carousel-indicators">
                        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0"
                            class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
                        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1"
                            aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
                        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2"
                            aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="carousel-item active">
                            <img src="img/uthappizza.png" class="d-block img-fluid" alt="uthappizza">
                            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block text-black">
                                <h5>First slide label</h5>
                                <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img src="img/buffet.png" class="d-block img-fluid" alt="buffet">
                            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block text-black">
                                <h5>First slide label</h5>
                                <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img src="img/alberto.png" class="d-block img-fluid" alt="alberto">
                            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block text-black">
                                <h5>First slide label</h5>
                                <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
                        data-bs-slide="prev">
                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                    </button>
                    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
                        data-bs-slide="next">
                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I don't know, maybe it's something with the css code. I would like to post it but I don't know how to do that.